# Does $(x - y)^2$ also mean $(y - x)^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology

if we have two numbers $x$ and $y$
we know that $(x - y)^2$ will equate to $(y - x)^2$, but is it satisfactory to say this:

$\{x,y \in \mathbb{R} \mid \sqrt{(x+y)^2+(x-y)^2}=1\}$

when I want to capture the $(y + x)$ and the $(y - x)$ case also? It is obvious that $(x + y) = (y +x)$, but is my expression rigorous enough to capture not just the $(x - y)$ case, but also the $(y - x)$ case?

Comment: Yes, $(x - y)^2 = (y - x)^2$. You can think about it this way: $$(x - y)^2 = ((-1)(y - x))^2 = (-1)^2(y - x)^2 = 1(y - x)^2 = (y - x)$$

Comment: Thanks for your help @TheoBendit, it seems obvious but was not sure if more notation was required to make it obvious in writing. Cheers.

Comment: $(x-y)^2=x^2-2xy+y^2$, $(y-x)^2=?$

Comment: In almost any context, just stating $(x - y)^2 = (y - x)^2$ is fine.

Comment: @Vasya Thankyou, but I really wasn't looking for any proof.  of a fact we all know. This fact, that (x + y) = (y+x) always, but (x - y) does not always equal (y - x) and this is why I wasn't sure if my expression above was comprehensive enough. It was more about math communication, than some proof. But I think I will just leave it as it is. I think I was overthinking it. Thanks both of you.